# Can I/how do I set up a heroku instance such that multiple users can administer it?

Tags: heroku, admin

We're looking to use a shared staging environment on Heroku, allowing multiple developers configuration/admin access to it.

How do I go about setting up an environment like that? Ideally, I'd want each developer to be able to use his own login info, in order to run commands against the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add your developers as collaborators to your application. Read more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing